# If a primal LP is infeasible, is it's dual LP always feasible?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I'm struggling with this question. I understand that with the strong duality theorem, the dual LP is infeasible when primal is unbounded (ex: [linear programming infeasibility, dual & primal relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782569/linear-programming-infeasibility-dual-primal-relation)).

My intuition tells me this is false, but I'm having trouble coming up with an example to prove it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linear programming problem of $$\min c^Tx$$
subject to $$Ax=b.$$

where $ A=0, c=b=1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Verify that both the primal and the dual are infeasible.